# Multiple Field Collection Sort

Tags: java, class, sorting, arraylist

I have a class Arraylist contains value 
String word, String expandedword, double confidence, double support

I want to sort the arraylist based on the confidence, and then based on the support.

I have succeed sort the arraylist based on confidence, but i failed to make a new method to sort the arraylist based on the support

this is my code to sort it based on confidence

```
public class ExpandedTerm implements Comparable<ExpandedTerm> {
String word;
String expandedWord;
double support;
double confidence;

public ExpandedTerm (String word,String expandedWord, double confidence,double support){
    this.word = word;
    this.expandedWord = expandedWord;
    this.support = support;
    this.confidence = confidence;
}

public String getWord(){
    return word;
}

public String expandedWord(){
    return expandedWord;
}

public Double getSupport(){
    return support;
}

public Double getConfidence(){
    return confidence;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ExpandedTerm conf) {
    return new Double(this.confidence).compareTo(new Double(conf.confidence));
}
```

I failed to make another method like compareTo, to sort it based on the support value.
How to sort it first by the confidence, and then make another method to sort it by the support value?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html or [use Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html).

Comment: +1 for Guava, good idea to reuse code whenever possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User Comparator for this. As compaarble provide functionality to sort on single type basis.
here is link where you found when to use comparable and comapartor
http://iandjava.blogspot.in/2012/10/comparable-and-comparator.html

Use multiple comparartor

- one for confidence

```
    public class ConfidanceComparator implements Comparator<ExpandedTerm> {
        @Override
        public int compare(final ExpandedTerm  o1, final ExpandedTerm  o2) {
            return new Double(o1.confidence).compareTo(new Double(o2.confidence));
        }
    }
```

- one for support

```
    public class SupportComparator implements Comparator<ExpandedTerm> {
        @Override
        public int compare(final ExpandedTerm  o1, final ExpandedTerm  o2) {
            return new Double(o1.support).compareTo(new Double(o2.support));
        }
    }
```

and use `Collections.sort(<List>, <comparator>)` adn you will get the desired list.

THis is only required when you want to sort either on confidance basis or support basis.
But if you required then first sort on confidance basis and if confidance is equal then check for support basis. then comparable is sufficient and is

```
public int compareTo(ExpandedTerm conf) {
    int compare = new Double(this.confidence).compareTo(new Double(conf.confidence));

    if (compare == 0) {
        compare = new Double(this.support).compareTo(new Double(conf.support));
    }
    return compare;
}
```

Comment: Everything about this answer is incorrect. There is no reason that `Comparable` can't be used here. -1 for a terrible answer.

Comment: @MattBall Comparable is not used because he want to compare on different basis sometime on the basis of confidance and some time on the baisis of support

Comment: I agree with @MattBall because you can write more than a single type basis comparison when implementing `Comparable`. The downside of using it is that you can't change that comparison method in case you need to use another comparison algorithm.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're getting at now. A different interpretation of than me. That's fine, but where are your generics?

Comment: Now after your last edit it can compile, but still doesn't directly answers OP question.

Comment: actually, i have to sort the arraylist based on the confidence.
1. Sort by confidence >>>> then arraylist sorted
2. Sort by support    >>>> then NEW result arraylist sorted

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, sorry i m not getting your point. Ahimsa wants to sort his array list on multiple basis so why this sol is not directly answer Op question. Can you please coorect me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AshishAggarwal so i have to make another class, Support Comparator and Confidence Comparator?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza & Matt is it possible use comparable more than single basis? can you explain please

Comment: @AhimsaAfrizal, From my point of view yes if you requirement is to sort list on multiple basis. I shared one link in which you found why and when to use comparator.

Comment: @MattBall If i give correct ans then you can remove your downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for your compareTo method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(ExpandedTerm other) {
    Double thisConfidence = new Double(getConfidence());
    Double otherConfidence = new Double(other.getConfidence());
    int compare = thisConfidence.compareTo(otherConfidence);

    if (compare == 0) {
        Double thisSupport = new Double(getSupport());
        Double otherSupport = new Double(other.getSupport());
        compare = thisSupport.compareTo(otherSupport);
    }
    return compare;
}
```

Basically only compare "support" if "confidence" is equal.

Comment: actually, i have to sort the arraylist based on the confidence.
1. Sort by confidence >>>> then arraylist sorted
2. Sort by support    >>>> then NEW result arraylist sorted

Answer (score 0):

I saw your reply that you want to sort once and sort again except differently, so I'm assuming you want to add a custom Comparator when you sort. Is this what you're looking for?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExpandedTerm term1 = new ExpandedTerm("a", "b", 1, 4);
    ExpandedTerm term2 = new ExpandedTerm("c", "d", 3, 2);

    List<ExpandedTerm> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(term1);
    list.add(term2);

    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<ExpandedTerm>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ExpandedTerm o1, ExpandedTerm o2) {
            return new Double(o2.confidence).compareTo(new Double(o1.confidence));
        }
    });
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Here's the output

```
[ExpandedTerm@2eeb3c84, ExpandedTerm@55d2162c]
[ExpandedTerm@55d2162c, ExpandedTerm@2eeb3c84]
```

Some other tips: make sure you implement the toString(), hashCode(), and equals() functions for your ExpandedTerm. These are essential for debugging and also for use in other Collections like HashMap, etc.

Comment: Instead of multiple answers always try to keep one ans and update it whenever required.